# Light intensity on materialed vs non materialed object

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light

I have 2 scenes, the first one I removed all materials, on the second one I didn't remove the materials. As you can see the spot light looks brighter on the scene that doesn't have materials than in the scene that has materials.

Does this occur because of the materials that I applied?

[image]
scene with materials

[image]
scene without materials

both of these scenes were given a spot lamp with default settings.

Here is another example:

[image]
with material

[image]
without material

Comment: Hello, you don't give enough informations, maybe show a screenshot, what do yo call non material object, what display mode are you talking about?

Comment: Hi Wahyu Roy, you have added two render engines in the tags: *Cycles* and *Blender-Render*. Which render engine are you using, when the problem is occuring. Please edit your question to remove the wrong tag. Also, why is the blender-id tag in the question?

Comment: Maybe with no material objects are shaded light gray by default. If your material textures are darker, probably the result will be darker too.